# stopping atd job at specified time

Tags: scheduling, at

I'm trying to schedule download at nights. I have created a `atd` job which starts download script at 2 AM. Now I want to stop the same job at 7 AM if it is still running. What I'm doing now is just `shutdown -h 7:00`. Is it possible to stop `atd` job at specified time?

Comment: Stop as in kill them or pause them to be resumed later?

Comment: @slm Does it make difference? I thought using "wget -c" will make both options look same.

Comment: Why not just have `at` run `killall wget` at the specified time?

Comment: Didn't know what exactly you were doing until you mentioned `wget`, so it's hard for us to say. Perhaps you could expand your Q so we know exactly what you're trying to do. Incidentally it can make a difference b/c we could just have the process go to sleep at 7AM vs. killing it and then resume later on in the day (would be one approach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a mechanism within `at` to allow you to specify a stop time. I would just schedule another `at` job at 7am that would  check if any of these at jobs are still running and kill them.

Answer (score 2):

`At` jobs are executed using a shell interpreter (on Linux, it is usually `/bin/sh`). It means that any command you are going to run as `at` job can be tracked by a PID number of the shell which is going to run that command. You can simply catch this PID with special shell variable `$$`. You can save it to a file (single quotes are mandatory to not expand it in your current session shell):

```
at 'echo $$ > /var/run/my_at_job.pid; your_command; rm /var/run/my_at_jon.pid' | at TIME_SPEC
```

and later, in another `at` job, you can kill the job and all its spawned child processes (`you_command`):

```
if [ -r /var/run/at_job.pid ]; then
  for PID in $(ps --ppid `cat /var/run/at_job.pid` -o pid | sed -e '1d'); do
    kill $PID
  done
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could incorporate the timeout into your job.

```
timeout "$(($(date +%s -d '7am') - $(date +%s)))" wget -c http://example.com/wibble
```

Alternatively, have your job write its process ID somewhere so that you can kill it. In the 2am job:

```
echo $$ >~/.at.download.pid
wget -c http://example.com/wibble
rm ~/.at.download.pid
```

In the 7am job:

```
if [ -e ~/.at.download.pid ]; then
  kill $(~/.at.download.pid)
  rm ~/.at.download.pid
fi
```